# Cursor appearing as pointer on margin area of an anchor tag only in IE7

Tags: css, cursor, margin

I have an anchor tag with some margin-right. In IE7, the cursor shows as pointer in the margin area which by default should be an arrow instead of hand pointer. It showld show as hand pointer only for the anchor tag and not on margin area. It works fine in every other browser but IE7.  How can i get it work? Thanks in advance

```
<div>
 <form>
  <a href=""><img src="xyz"/></a>
 </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
 float:right;
 padding-top:15px;
}
form{
 margin:0;
 width:100%;
}
a{
 margin-right:35px;
}
img{
 border:medium none;
}
```

Comment: try to close img tag `<img src="xyz" />`

Comment: Sorry! that was a typo

Comment: can't reproduce your issue http://jsfiddle.net/t3p5bwkw/2/ =( on ie 9

Comment: The above code is just a prototype. Actually I have an image(cancel button) inside the anchor tag. When am clicking anywhere in the margin area it is clickable i.e. cancel is working. Idealy it should work only on click of the cancel img and not on click in anywhere in the margin area. Let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out the solution to this in IE7. But have found an alternative to it.
I have put the anchor tag inside a span tag and gave it the margin needed and removed the margin for anchor tag:

```
<span style="margin-right:35px">
    <a href=""><img src="abc"/></a>
</span>
```

This works well. But doesnot anwer the issue in question.